# Bash sed -i update with trailing backslash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, bin

i want to run this :

```
sed -i -e "s/\($user hard nproc \).*/\1{value here ending with /}/" /etc/something.conf
```

here, {value here ending with /} is like ***100/*** or ***abc/***

however if i just put / like :

```
sed -i -e "s/\($user hard nproc \).*/\1abc//" /etc/something.conf
```

i get this error :
unknown option to `s'

I have been tring to fix this but can't think of any solution...

Basically what i am trying to do is update my old value from 
"**username hard nproc 10**" 
to "**username hard nproc 10**"
with the "****".

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, your question is not clear. Please post sample Input_file with expected output file in code tags and let me know then.

Comment: updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either escape the trailing slash or use a different character for the expression. i.e.:

```
sed -i "s/\($user hard nproc \).*/\1abc\//" /etc/cgrules.conf
```

or

```
sed -i "s#\($user hard nproc \).*#\1abc/#" /etc/cgrules.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Following simple sed is working for me well.

```
echo "username hard nproc 10" | sed 's/username hard nproc 10/username hard nproc 10**/g'
username hard nproc 10**
```

Let's say you want to have these values old and new into variables then following may help yon in same.

```
old_value="username hard nproc 10"
new_value="username hard nproc 10**"
echo "username hard nproc 10" | sed "s/$old_value/$new_value/g"
```

Output will be as follows.

```
username hard nproc 10**
```

Similarly you could mention your Input_file in spite of echo here. Also use `-i` option of `sed` if you want to save changes in Input_file itself(I would suggest run above codes without doing changes in Input_file and then run with `-i` option once you are satisfied with results).

Answer (score 0):

In sed, whenever you want to do something with a `/` that gets in the way of the `/` used for a command, the simplest thing to do is to use a different delimiter for the command.  For example:

```
sed -e "s@\($user hard nproc \).*@\1{value here ending with /}@"
```

will work just fine.  `s/pattern/repl/flags` is just a convention, and you can just as well use `s@pattern@repl@flags`